# VNRecognizeTextRequest stopped recognising text in iOS 15

Tags: swift, iphone, ios15, visionkit, ios-vision

I'm using `VNRecognizeTextRequest` via `VNImageRequestHandler` with following settings:

```
 request.recognitionLevel = .accurate
 request.usesLanguageCorrection = false
 request.recognitionLanguages = ["en-US", "de-DE"]
```

I'm using real time capturing from `AVFoundation`, then converting `CMSampleBuffer` to `CVPixelBuffer` and send it to `VNImageRequestHandler`.

Basically the code is taken from Apple sample:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/reading_phone_numbers_in_real_time

The thing is it was working well until iOS 15 came. Then it stopped recognising the text with following errors:

```
Could not determine an appropriate width index for aspect ratio 0.0062
Could not determine an appropriate width index for aspect ratio 0.0078
Could not determine an appropriate width index for aspect ratio 0.0089
...
```

Generally I was able to partly fix it by changing `recognitionLevel` from `.accurate` to `.fast`. But I prefer the first more as it gives better results and sometimes `.fast` recognises only individual characters from words, e.g. if there is a number with spaces like `"7  2 5 6"` it can recognise only 7 or 2 and so on.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.